# Get status of the the File or folder copying is complete

Tags: c#, copy, detection, filesystemwatcher

I am planning to develop a File organize software which detect files arrive to special folder and copy those files to specific folder (Ex .txt files goes to Text Doc folder). I'm using  `FileSystemWatcher`.

for detect files. So I want to know whether the file or folder copying operation (Manually copy file or folder) is finish or not by C# code.

With single file program is ok. but for multiple files need to improve the program.

I used this loop to check whether file is release or not, but with large files this makes the program not responded.

```
void File_move(string source,string destination)
        {
            EE:
                try
                {
                    File.Move(source, destination);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Waiting for file copping complete";
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    goto EE;
                }

        }
```

Comment: You cannot get the currently running status of the operation. But the FileSystemWatcher should raise a "Created" event or something when the file has been created - the problem with that is that I think it is created when the copying just started and is running. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You are right.It is created when the copying just started... I googled lot. I don't think there will be an answer. Thanks for reply

Comment: You could keep listening to FileSizeChanged events or something like that (or last access date, even though I also think it is set once when copying starts). You would, however, need to find out when copying stopped (maybe after some time of no FileSizeChanged events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time I found a solution for my own question. Here is the link for get file copy progress in both c# and vb.net

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CopyFileEx.html

In this sample code we can get progress of copping a file

```
private CopyProgressResult CopyProgressHandler(long total, long transferred, long streamSize, long StreamByteTrans, uint dwStreamNumber,CopyProgressCallbackReason reason, IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData)
    {
        Progressbar.Max=Convert.ToInt32(total);
        Progressbar.Value=Convert.ToInt32(transferred);
        Application.Doevents();
        return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
    }
```

*long total* gives total size and *long transferred* gives current progress